# svn: how to move changes from trunk to a branch

Tags: svn

Let's say I fixed something and committed the change to the trunk. Now apparently we already have a branch for the upcoming release. How would you go and copy/apply the changes to the new branch as well?

Comment: Already exists a question about this. It could help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611693/merging-of-branch-to-trunk-in-svn-using-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd merge the changes back-  [svn merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html)